# RecyclerView is Selecting more than one item when click in Android

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, selection

I am working with RecyclerView and the issue is when is click on one item it become selected.after That when click on second item the first and second item both are selected at the same time.
Code For Onclick:

```
init {
    itemView.setOnClickListener {
        modesList[adapterPosition].isSelected = true
        val modelWrapper = modesList[adapterPosition]
        val formatModel = modelWrapper.mode
        itemListener.recyclerViewListClicked(
            formatModel,
            formatModel.getId(),
            formatModel.modeName,
            formatModel.modeName_Number,
            formatModel.modeBrightnessProgressBar,
            formatModel.modeSpeedProgressBar,
            formatModel.colorValues,
            adapterPosition
        )
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should get the position of an item in your adapter and pass it to the activity or fragment and simply do your job.

Here you can see an example.

```kotlin
class  MyAdapter : RecyclerView.Adapter<MyAdapter.MyAdapterViewHolder>() {

    inner class MyAdapterViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView)

    private val differCallback = object : DiffUtil.ItemCallback<Item>() {
        override fun areItemsTheSame(oldItem: YourEntityObject, newItem: YourEntityObject): Boolean {
            return oldItem.id == newItem.id
        }

        override fun areContentsTheSame(oldItem: YourEntityObject, newItem: YourEntityObject): Boolean {
            return oldItem == newItem
        }
    }

    val differ = AsyncListDiffer(this, differCallback)

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): MyAdapterViewHolder{
        return MyAdapterViewHolder(LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.item, parent, false))
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return differ.currentList.size
    }

    private var onItemClickListener: ((YourEntityObject) -> Unit)? = null

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: MyAdapterViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val info = differ.currentList[position]
        holder.itemView.apply {
            
            setOnClickListener {
                onItemClickListener?.let { it(repoInfo) }
            }
        }
    }

    fun setOnItemClickListener(listener: (YourEntityObject) -> Unit) {
        onItemClickListener = listener
    }
}
```

- Now in your fragment just simply write as following.

```kotlin
 private lateinit var myAdapter: MyAdapter 

   override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)    
        setupRecyclerView()    
        adapterOperation()
    }


  private fun adapterOperation() {
        with(myAdapter) {
          
            setOnItemClickListener {
                toast(it.your_entity_property)// for example toast the name of list item
            }
            
        }
    }


 private fun setupRecyclerView() {
       adapter = MyAdapter()
        your_recyclerveiw.apply {     
            adapter = myAdapter
            layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(activity)
        }
    }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to declare itemid and itemviewtype in your Recycler Adapter to overcome this.

```
 @Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    return position;
}
```

Comment: Can you please explain the reson of doing so? Thankyou